# Flipping an image

Tags: java, image, graphics, transform, flip

I am creating a tile game where I need to flip images. With the code I have it produces this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (-1) and height (-1) cannot be <= 0
```

from this line:

```
Image newImage = gc.createCompatibleImage(
        image.getWidth(null),
        image.getHeight(null),
        Transparency.BITMASK);
```

here is the coding i have:

```
public Image getMirrorImage(Image image) {
    return getScaledImage(image, -1, 1);
}

private Image getScaledImage(Image image, float x, float y) {
    // set up the transform
    AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
    transform.scale(x, y);
    transform.translate(
        (x-1) * image.getWidth(null) / 2,
        (y-1) * image.getHeight(null) / 2);

    // create a transparent (not translucent) image
    Image newImage = gc.createCompatibleImage(
        image.getWidth(null),
        image.getHeight(null),
        Transparency.BITMASK);

    // draw the transformed image
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)newImage.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, transform, null);
    g.dispose();

    return newImage;
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what i might need to do different or how i can make it work? Many thanks

Comment: Try multiplying the scale by -1 instead of setting it to -1.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 3):

It's possible for `image.getWidth(null)` and `image.getHeight(null)` to return -1 if they're not known yet. Image processing can be done concurrently and it might still be going when you try to call those methods (even locally it'll do this IIRC). Here's a snippet of code I've used before to wait for an image to be loaded before trying to access its width and height:

```
private void waitForImage(Image image) {
    Container container = new Container();
    MediaTracker tracker = new MediaTracker(container);
    tracker.addImage(image, 0);
    try {
        tracker.waitForID(0, 1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

I just tried a local test and the wait times were generally 1ms for some small images. It's not really any additional time, it just forces your code to wait for the last stage to complete to get the width and height.

Comment: Either that or use `ImageIO.read(File/URL/InputStream)` which blocks until loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your post, could you give an example of how to encorporate it in my program so i dont get the error?

Comment: @Andrew: oh yeah, that's right there is a more modern way to do it. I was reminded of some image scaling I did a decade ago in an applet, so I referenced that first for some reason :)

Comment: @mimis40 "could you give an example.." I'll consider that at the very moment you post an **SSCCE.**  For the image, feel free to use (lot-link to) an [image listed on my media page](http://pscode.org/media/#image).

Comment: @mimis40: it looks like you just need to call the `waitForImage()` code I posted at the beginning of your `getScaledImage()` method.

Comment: @WhiteFang34: Sad to say what you suggested did not work. I still got the same error i did at the beginning. Do you have any ideas what else could fix the error?

Comment: @WhiteFang34: Ive found through debugging that the problem is not flipping the image, but in setting it to be transparent. Is it possible that the .png image I am working with has lost it's transparency?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to flip the image is by negative scaling it. Example:

```
g2.drawImage(image, x, y, -width, height, null);
```

That will flip it vertically. This will flip it horizontally:

```
g2.drawImage(image, x, y, width, -height, null);
```